# xhr.getAllResponseHeaders() getting undefined in IPHONE Safari browser

Tags: javascript, iphone, response-headers

I am sending an authorization token from backend via headers:

```
access-control-allow-headers:     accept, content-type, x-access…requested-            with, authorization
access-control-allow-methods:   GET,PUT,POST,DELETE
access-control-allow-origin:    *
access-control-expose-headers:  *
authorization:  BEARER xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
content-type:   application/json; charset=utf-8
```

but when i access this from IPHONE's Safari browser it gives me undefined, but works normally on all other phones and browsers

```
resolve({'token':xhr.getResponseHeader('authorization')})
```

expected the output as token but gets undefined

Comment: Did you get any response (with other headers) for the API call in Safari browser?

Comment: Getting undefined via getAllResponseHeaders();

Answer (score 0):

Set the headers with specific name, not with *.

```
access-control-expose-headers: X-Your-Custom-Header, X-Your-Custom-Header2, ...
```

Refer [Apple developer link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/XHR.html) and [HTML5Rocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)